# Strange behavior of convertToWorldSpace for MenuItems in CCMenu

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-html5

I have a menu attached to the layer . In the menu 4 items aligned vertically. I decleare the menu in this way (Warning! This is Javascript. Using COCOS2D-Html5, the framework is the same as per iphone):

```
        menuHeight = sumofMenuItemsHeight(CategoryMiniSpriteArray);
        var newMenu = cc.Menu.create(CategoryMiniSpriteArray);

        newMenu.setAnchorPoint(cc.PointMake(1,1));
        newMenu.setPosition(cc.PointMake( 
                            ScreenSize.width, ScreenSize.height - (menuHeight / 2)
                            ));
        newMenu.alignItemsVertically();
```

After that at some point in the program I wanna to get the absolute coordinates of the menuitems relative to the screen.
And I execute this code:

```
var itemPosition = miniSprite.convertToWorldSpace(miniSprite.getPosition());
```

I get a very strange behavior. The X coordinate returned perfectly matches the real position. If I try to place this way:

```
sprite.setPosition(itemPosition);
```

another sprite to that coordinates X is perfectly aligned with the menuitems.
The problem is the Y. For every MenuItem I get a shifted Y but that's not all. The  difference of Y between the menuitems is 2x times the menuitem height. So not only shifted Y but even shifted between items. What I'm doing wrong ? This is not the WorldSpace.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that I'm calling convertToWorldSpace in the wrong way:

```
var itemPosition = miniSprite.convertToWorldSpace(miniSprite.getPosition());
```

Should be:

```
var itemPosition = miniSprite.getParent().convertToWorldSpace(miniSprite.getPosition());
```

I needed to call convertToWorldSpace from the CCMenu. From the parent and not from the child.